# Link_to duplicate a link in the html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code

```
<% @sectors.each do |sector| %>
   <li><%= link_to sectors_path(name: sector.name) do %>
    <i class="<%= sector.logo_awesome %>"></i> <%= sector.name %></li>
   <% end %>
<% end %>`
```

When i post this code in my file, I have this HTML

```
<li><a href="/sectors?name=General">
<i class="fa fa-globe"></i> General</a></li>

<a href="/sectors?name=General">
</a>
```

I don't understand why the last `<a href="/sectors?name=General"></a>` is put inside the html. The ruby code should only render the first part I guess ? (between the `<li>`)

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing your tags wrong. Change to:

```
<% @sectors.each do |sector| %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to sectors_path(name: sector.name) do %>
            <i class="<%= sector.logo_awesome %>"></i> <%= sector.name %>
        <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok I see, I have to be more carefull.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 <% @sectors.uniq.each do |sector| %>
       <li>
        <%= link_to sectors_path(name: sector.name) do %>
            <i class="<%= sector.logo_awesome %>"></i> <%= sector.name %>
       <% end %>
       </li>
    <% end %>`
```